# Vaadin - using FileDownloader without a button

Tags: java, download, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to use the FileDownloader of Vaadin without extending a Button. The final result should be that the user clicks on an entry of a table, and that should then trigger the download.

With the FileDownloader it works fine, but it seems like you need to extend a Button to make this work. Here is the code so far if it helps:

```
        table.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener()    {
        public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
            Map<String, Object> dok = dbService.getDokument(event.getItem().getItemProperty("Id").getValue().toString());

            myResource = createResource(dok);
            fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
            //HERE I WANT TO TRIGGER THE DOWNLOAD
        } 
    });

private StreamResource createResource(Map<String, Object> dok) {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            byte[] file = (byte[]) dok.get("DATA");

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bos.write(file, 0, file.length);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());

        }
    }, getValue(dok.get("DOK_NAME")));
}
```

Comment: Can't you add the button to the layout, but set it to hidden?

Comment: Triggering the download itself isn't the problem, the problem is that everytime the table is clicked the button gets a new Extension, so for every click it adds one more file to the download. I need to do this without the extension of the button.

Comment: I take it it's not an option to use the [`fileDownloader.setFileDownloadResource(resource)`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html#setFileDownloadResource-com.vaadin.server.Resource-) method to avoid adding a new extension?

Comment: You could create a Button that you don't make visible, and then call the button.click() method in the itemClick() method.